# Mypy `unsupported operand types` after inline checking for is None in typing.Optional[int] argument

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to declare an argument to be optional with the `typing` library. Since this argument can be either `int | None`, if I try to do a math expression with it I first have to check if it's `None`, otherwise an error would raise.

Snippet of my code with code partially implemented:

```py
def foo(filename: str, size: Optional[int] = None):
    # open filename, if it doesn't exist, create it if size is not None and size is multiple  of someConstant
    # if file exists, read and get trueFileSize
    ...
    if size is not None and trueFileSize != size * someConstant:
        # if trueFileSize is different than size times someConstant, rewrites file here
        ...
```

As I understand, if an `and` logical operator first check returns `False`, the subsequent checks are ignored, like in C. If I'm correct, why `mypy` is telling me this

```
... error: Unsupported operand types for * ("int" and "None")
```

when I'm first checking if `size` is not `None`?

I get that rewriting the code in two if statements solves the problem, but why `mypy` can't deal with the previous snippet but doesn't raise an error with the following snippet?

```py
def foo(filename: str, size: Optional[int] = None):
    # open filename, if it doesn't exist, create it size is not None
    # if file exists, read and get trueFileSize
    ...
    if size is not None:
        if trueFileSize != size * someConstant: # mypy: doesn't raise error
            # if trueFileSize is different than size times someConstant, rewrite file
            ...
```

Comment: This looks like a limitation of `mypy`. You should report it here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Comment: Issue opened at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12275. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Because static analysis is not magic and actually quite hard to do in a dynamic language like Python.

Comment: What versions of mypy and python are you using? I do not see any error.

Comment: Which version of mypy are you using? This seems to work https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.931&python=3.10&gist=6133504b68fa1e74e844d0fc280ee42f

Comment: Multiple people cannot reproduce this. Please post a [mre], and add the used Python and mypy versions to your question to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if size is not None and trueFileSize != (size * someConstant):
```

Put multiplication in parentheses to prioritize it.

Comment: Could you explain why this would solve the issue? Multiplication already has a higher priority than comparisons (see [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the Python documentation)

Comment: First of all, please let me know if the solution worked. If yes, then it will be one of weird behaviors that I've seen in Mypy. I've checked it here: https://www.online-python.com/YtAgo4V9p8

Comment: I check this code in pure python and it worked fine without parentheses too.

Comment: So why do you recommend the parantheses? Like you said, they are not necessary.

Comment: In some situations, adding parentheses has helped me to fix the problem.